# What's wrong with the four highlighted parts of this foreign-written Chinese passage about campus bells?

Tags: grammar, usage, meaning-in-context

My friend on WeChat sent a funny example of foreigners writing Chinese ([here](http://www.sohu.com/a/206310345_425113)).  Here's one image from that site (click for larger image):

[image: Foreign Chinese-learning materials]

I transcribe the passage below (I tried to make sure I copied it correctly), and I offer my translation (which might not be accurate).  I presume there's something wrong with the underlined phrases.  I'm not fully clear on this though; I add my comments below.

**Question**: What is wrong with the four underlined phrases, and what should it say instead?

> 一个[提案](http://dict.cn/%E6%8F%90%E6%A1%88)
> <sup>Yīgè tí'àn</sup>
> A Proposal
>
> 星期日
> <sup>Xīngqírì</sup>
> Sunday
>
> 本班同学[凑集](http://dict.cn/%E5%87%91%E9%9B%86)[款子](http://dict.cn/%E6%AC%BE%E5%AD%90)买一具钟，作为毕业[纪念品](http://dict.cn/%E7%BA%AA%E5%BF%B5%E5%93%81)案。
> <sup>Běn bān tóngxué còují kuǎn zi mǎi yī jù zhōng, zuòwéi bìyèjìniànpǐn àn</sup>
> This class's classmates gather money together to buy a bell, as a graduation momento.

Google Translate suggests [筹集](http://dict.cn/%E7%AD%B9%E9%9B%86) (chóují; collect money) instead of [凑集](http://dict.cn/%E5%87%91%E9%9B%86) (còují).

> 是**前两班**的同学[修](http://dict.cn/%E4%BF%AE)的，校园里的[**茅亭**](http://dict.cn/%E8%8C%85%E4%BA%AD)是去年毕业的一班同学[造](http://dict.cn/%E9%80%A0)的。
> <sup>Shì qián liǎng bān de tóngxué xiūde, xiàoyuán lǐ de máotíng shì qùnián bìyè de yī bān tóngxué zào de.</sup>
> This is what the students in the first two classes made; the campus's pavilion was made by the students who graduated last year.

Here 前两班 is a bit confusing, e.g., maybe it means "two classes prior" instead.  I don't know what's wrong with [茅亭](http://dict.cn/%E8%8C%85%E4%BA%AD) (máotíng) = pavilion.

> **这些都**[**表示**](http://dict.cn/%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA)毕业生[对于](http://dict.cn/%E5%AF%B9%E4%BA%8E)母校的依恋，现在[轮](http://dict.cn/%E8%BD%AE)到我们毕业了，我们当然也要留一件纪念品。
> <sup>Zhèxiē dōu biǎoshì bìyè shēng duìyú mǔxiào de yīliàn, xiànzài lún dào wǒmen bìyèle, wǒmen dāngrán yě yào liú yī jiàn jìniànpǐn.</sup>
> These both indicate the graduates' attachment to their almamater, and now that it's our turn to graduate, we, of course, also want to leave a momento.

I'm not sure what's wrong with "这些都表示" simply meaning "these both express".

> 我们学校里上课下课都[摇铃](http://dict.cn/%E6%91%87%E9%93%83)，我们的意思是买**一具钟**来[代替](http://dict.cn/%E4%BB%A3%E6%9B%BF)铃。
> <sup>Wǒmen xuéxiào lǐ shàngkè xiàkè dōu yáo líng, wǒmen de yìsi shì mǎi yī jù zhōng lái dàitì líng.</sup>
> We ring a bell at the start and end of class on our campus, we mean to buy a bell instead.

It looks like [具](http://dict.cn/%E5%85%B7) is the wrong measure word for 钟 = bell.

> 钟
> <sup>Zhōng</sup>
> Bell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Google Translate suggests 筹集 (chóují; collect money) instead of 凑集 (còují)*.

凑集 means a 'group of people footing the bill together'

筹集 means 'raise funds'

> *Here 前两班 is a bit confusing*

From the context, '前两班' in "是前两班的同学修的" seems to refer to "previous two school years of the same class"   It should write " 是**前两屆畢業的**本班同学修的 (built by the graduated students of this class from the previous two school years)

> *I don't know what's wrong with 茅亭 (máotíng) = pavilion.*

'茅亭' is a pavilion with a thatch roof. There's nothing wrong with using '茅亭' here.

> I'm not sure what's wrong with "这些都表示" simply meaning "these both express".

'都' here means 'all'. The sentence "这些**都**表示" means "**All** these indicate"

> *It looks like 具 is the wrong measure word for 钟 = bell.*

- 摇铃 is small handheld or hanging bell
- 钟 (or 吊钟) is a bigger bell that you ring it by hitting it with a mallet.  usually sit on a table or hanging in a frame, but not handheld

Classifier for 钟 like this should be '口' as in "一口钟",

Answer (score 2):

Building on the above (because I lack the reputation points to comment):

If the pavilion is in fact not thatched, use 亭子.

You can use 這 as a straight demonstrative pronoun ("this").

The correct quantifier for the kind of 钟 in the picture is 座.

Comment: 座 is more suitable as classifier for 钟楼.  For the 钟 itself, the common classifier is  still '口'

Comment: e.g. " 这座钟楼有三口大钟 " is better than " 这座钟楼有三座大钟 "